# slam map edit or view tools

Tags: ros2, slam, cartographer

I'm a newer ros2 and slam engineer.
Recently, we use the imu and 2D lidar run the Cartographer.
However, it alwayes break in different place everytime.
And I found that a company use the Karto and a tool to moditify it. Below is that video link.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrlEQ1sTLVw

But now I couldn't find this tool anymore.
Could anyone recommend other tools to moditify builded map but not image tool.
Or give me some advise? Thanks!

Comment: Everyone I've seen just edits the .PGM file directly, using some image editor. But you've said you don't want to do that: please add detail to your question to highlight what specific functionality you're looking for here (ideally, without needing to follow some link that may expire).

Comment: I hope the function like the video in the article. I could pull specific point to match two point's laser scan. And then adjust whole map.
Becuase I need to build large environment. But my slam will not closure because of shift in the end map.